# Can I write a lambda function in pointfree notation in haskell? If so, how?

Tags: haskell

For example, if I want to convert: \x -> x + 100, how do I write in pointfree notation? \ -> id + 100 does not seem to work

Answer (score 5):

You may write any of these, per your taste:

```
(+100)
(+) 100 -- not 100% faithful if your Num instance is weird
flip (+) 100
```

See also [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree), a tool for answering questions of this form automatically.

Comment: To explain on “weird `Num` instance” – all the standard types in `Prelude` have commutative addition, hence `x + 100` is always the same as `100 + x`, and `\x -> 100 + x` is what can be made point-free as `(+) 100`. However, Haskell allows to define new types with [`Num` instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) that behave entirely different, and not satisfy `100 + x ≡ x + 100`. That would usually be a bad idea. For multiplication, `x * y ≠ y * x` actually makes sense in some contexts, e.g. [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).